# Neither gulp-tinypng nor gulp-imagemin optimise png

Tags: javascript, gulp, png, gulp-imagemin

I want to add a png optimizer in my gulp workflow.
I've tried to both gulp-tinypng and gulp-imagemin.

**I work with gulp 4.0.0**
Here are my functions :

```
function tinypng() {
  return (
    gulp
      .src(pkg.paths.src.img + '**/*.png')
      .pipe($.cache($.tinypng('MyApiKey')))      
      .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.prod.img))              // Envoie le fichier dans le dossier de production
      .pipe($.browserSync.stream())                     // Relance le browser
      .pipe($.notify({ message: 'Png task complete' })) 
  );
}

function images() {
  return (
    gulp
      .src(pkg.paths.src.img + '**/*.*')
      .pipe($.cache($.imagemin([ 
        $.imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
        $.imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
        $.imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 7}) 
        ])))                                                // cache et optimise les images
      .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.prod.img))                  // Envoie le fichier dans le dossier de production
      .pipe($.browserSync.stream())                         // Relance le browser
      .pipe($.notify({ message: 'Images task complete' })) 
  );
}

gulp.task('tinypng', tinypng);
gulp.task('images', images);
```

I run my test with a png weighting ***1002 Ko***.

If I use the website [tinypng](//tinypng.com), the weight goes down to ***279 Ko***

Both functions run smoothly, no error, files are copied where they should be, ***but the weight of the files isn't reduce***. It's like it's copying the original file.

I'd be glad to get some help here, because I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: Taking a guess: does it reduce the filesize if you run imagemin without any options ie `$.imagemin()`? What about if you run it without `$.cache`?

Comment: @Zweihänder, Hello, thanks for your replay. I went with    
function images() {  
  return (  
    gulp  
      .src(pkg.paths.src.img + '**/*.*')  
      .pipe($.imagemin())  
      .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.prod.img))                  // Envoie le fichier dans le   dossier de production  
      .pipe($.browserSync.stream())                         // Relance le browser  
      .pipe($.notify({ message: 'Images task complete' }))   
  );  
}  
 Same result, the .png isn't optimised